# how to implement by writing own addFirst method? What else do I need to add?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.addFirst(2);
        l.addFirst("c");
        System.out.println(l);
    }
    private  Node first;
    private class Node {
        public Object data;
        public Node next;
    }

    public void addFirst(Object obj){
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data=obj;
        newNode.next=first;
        first=newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you want or expect the behavior to be? And what problem are you having? What steps have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: You probably want to override `public String toString() {...}`.

Comment: And remove the imports. You don't need them here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have implemented the `addFirst` method, but you need to implement a `toString()` method so that you can print out the contents of the list.

For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    Node n = first;
    while (n != null) {
        s += n.data + "\n";
        n = n.next;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Prints:

> c
>   
> 2

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class LinkedList{
        public static  void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
            l.addFirst("c");
            l.addFirst("7");
System.out.println(l);
        }
        private Node first;
        static class Node {
            String data;
            Node next;
        }
        private void addFirst(String s){
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data=s;
            newNode.next=first;
            first=  newNode;
        }
    }
    //  Is something wrong with addfirst method? Its still not working.
```